# keycloak deployment on kubernetes (GKE) : Ingress class -- nginx VS gce

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to deploy keycloak on google kubernetes engine and got it working using the ingress.class type **nginx** as follows

> kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx

Full manifest can be found here
https://github.com/vsomasvr/keycloak-gke/blob/master/keycloak-gke-ingress/ingress.yaml

But, my intent is to use ingress.class type "**gce**". For that I had changed the ingress annotations from the following

```
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
```

to the following

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
annotations: kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
```

After the above change, I consistently get a message indicating that the ingress has unhealthy backend (0/3).
I wonder what other changes would "**gce**" require when "**nginx**" could run without any issues.

I ensured that its not a firewall issue as the ports that the app is using are allowed for all, I also have *livenessProbe* and *readinessProbe* setting in place.

Is there anything else that this configuration is missing?

I placed all the manifest files here
https://github.com/vsomasvr/keycloak-gke/tree/master/keycloak-gke-ingress

Any help is appreciated

## EDIT

I had added the annotation

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
```

to the *nginx* ingress, tested & ensured that it would not cause any conflict. The app worked without issues.

On the other end, the *gce* ingress has the same behavior even when I remove the above mentioned annotation

Answer (score 0):

Your service seems to be configured to use HTTP traffic, which means the health checks for the Load Balancer will also use HTTP traffic (port 80) yet you are using an annotation that disables HTTP

> [kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"](https://paste.googleplex.com/6481015199498240)

Comment: I agree with your observation. But, in this case I think it didn't matter, just to ensure that, I added that annotation to the nginx-ingress and ensured that it works (added info to the question to cover that point). It has to do with the keycloak config, enabling "proxy address forwarding" which works behind loadbalancer serving the https traffic.

Comment: the difference though is how GCE LB use Health checks. I am pretty sure the GCE LB health check does not immediately return a 200 response (which is necessary for a backend to be considered healthy), with the redirect, the health check may be getting a 3xx response initially which leads to unhealthy backends.

Comment: The same thing is happening to me. When disabling HTTP, my ingress complains backend services are unknown. How would you go about configuring the service to use HTTPS? The service points to the correct port.

Comment: are you using network endpoint groups? That should resolve any issues with disabling http on the LB. The endpoint groups should then pass any health checks same as your readiness probes without changing the service ports to HTTPS